# Overwrite of Fooman EmailAttachments works about 50%

Tags: magento-1.9, module, overrides, localisation, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm using Fooman's EmailAttachments extension on Magento CE 1.9.2.4 - or I try to.
This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <config>
    <modules>
        <NewName_EmailAttachments>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </NewName_EmailAttachments>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <emailattachments>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_order>NewName_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_Order</order_pdf_order>
                    <order_pdf_bundleitems>NewName_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_BundleItems</order_pdf_bundleitems>
                 </rewrite>
            </emailattachments>
        </models>
    </global>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>Newdefault</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores> </config>
```

As you can see I also tried to make it use a custom admin backend design so I can use my own translation files. This worked for other classes I made overwrites. Any ideas why not here?

This is the module's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <NewName_EmailAttachments>
             <active>true</active>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
             <depends>
                <Fooman_EmailAttachments />
            </depends>
    </NewName_EmailAttachments>
  </modules>
</config>
```

The really interesting now is that the overwrite of Order_Pdf_Order works but the overwrite of Order_Pdf_BundleItems doesn't. Magento still takes the core class where the Fooman overwrite points to. How can I change that? Is there something more to do?
To make it complete, here are the class definitions of the override files:

```
class NewName_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_Order extends Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_Order
{
...
```

and

```
class NewName_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_BundleItems extends Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_BundleItems
{
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The `BundleItems` class having an uppercase "i" im pretty sure your rewrite should be:

```
<order_pdf_bundleItems>NewName_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_BundleItems</order_pdf_bundleItems>
```

Comment: Yes capitalisation is important here - see https://github.com/fooman/emailattachments/blob/master/app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/etc/config.xml#L33. @Stefan Keen to hear what changes you needed to make to support your use case (feel free to leave a comment on our github page).